# How do I create a loop for this action in Swift?

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, xcode12

I am made an app in xcode that vibrates with a button but i would like to add gaps of a certain duration during the vibration. I am using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) and I would like to add gaps while the vibration is occuring. Then add a beep for 3 sec and use a loop to repeat this action. This is what I have so far. How do I create a loop? I am testing using an iphone 7 plus.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep", ofType: "mp3")
        do{
            // initialized it with URL created above
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
    }

    }
    @IBAction func PressMe(_ sender: Any) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        for _ in 1...6 {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.002)
            let seconds = 1.0
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
                self.audioPlayer.play()
            }
            
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just like this ..

```
play
  play a sound
  timer 2 seconds call gap

gap 
  stop playing the sound
  timer 2 seconds call play
```

Comment: what is the actual code? Can you write out the code